# Show that is continuous and coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, boundary-value-problem, bilinear-form

I have the following boundary value problem, where $k, q \in \mathbb{R}$ are given.

$$-u'' + ku' +qu = f,\qquad  u(0)=u(1)= 0$$

What I want to prove is that the bilinear form, associated with this BVP, is continuous and also coercive.

By definition we have that, a bilinear forma $(\cdot,\cdot)$ on a normed linear space H is said to continuous if $\exists C< \infty$ such that
$$|a(v, w)|\le C‖v‖_H‖w‖_H, \qquad\forall v, w\in H$$
So this is what I should prove in order to show it is continuous.

I tried to write the variational formulation for this is as:
$$V=H^1(0,1)$$
$$a(u, v)=\int_0^1(u'v'+ku'v+quv)\ dx$$
$$F(v)=(f, v)$$

So I have that,
$$|a(u,v)|\le\Bigg|\int_0^1ku'v\ dx\Bigg|+\Bigg|\int_0^1u'v'+quv\ dx\Bigg|$$
$$\le|k|||u'||_{L^2}||v||_{L^2}+\Bigg|\int_0^1u'v'+quv\ dx\Bigg|$$

Not sure how to proceed from here, can anyone help?
Also if I made any mistakes, please tell me.

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwarz and Hoelder inequality, plus definition of $H^1$ norm. Your steps are going into the right direction.