# Question about $H^1$ norm

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, bilinear-form

The $H^1$ norm is given by:

$$(u,v)_{H^1}=\int_0^1u′v′+\int_0^1uv$$

But in a problem that I'm solving, I have a constant in the second integral:
$$|a(u,v)|\le|k|||u'||_{L^2}||v||_{L^2}+\Bigg|\int_0^1u'v'+quv\ dx\Bigg|$$

How can I manipulate this part below in order to use the $H^1$ norm?
$$\Bigg|\int_0^1u'v'+quv\ dx\Bigg|$$

Comment: I assume you're trying to bound a bilinear operator $a := a(\cdot,\cdot)$, whose definition is based on $\|\cdot\|_{H^1}$, in order to show that $a$ is continuous/bounded? What is this constant $q$?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Yeah, I'm trying to show that it's continuous. This is the problem: 
 [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453482/show-that-is-continuous-and-coercive)

Comment: why not estimate $|\int quv| \le |q|\int |u|\cdot |v|$?